# On a Conjecture: "The God of X will be the Son of X"

Tags: exegesis, old-testament, new-testament, messiah

In an answer given here: [On Inferring That the Redeemer Will Spring from the Race of Shem](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/96437/on-inferring-that-the-redeemer-will-spring-from-the-race-of-shem), Paul Chernoch makes the very interesting observation:

> Going through the ESV, I checked every verse with the construction "God of X". When X is the name of the person, these are the only names ever used:
>
> - Shem
> - Abraham
> - Isaac
> - Jacob
> - Israel
> - David
> - Elijah
> - Hezekiah
> - Shadrach, Meshech and Abednego
> - Daniel
>   The last three are references made by foreign kings, with Hezekiah being mocked and the remaining ones being honored, but this honor of being named in a "God of X" construction was not given by a prophet. Even so, Hezekiah was in Jesus' genealogy.

> This leaves Elijah alone as not being in the line of the savior. He is the exception that proves the rule: a person being honored by being named in the phrase "God of X" is being granted a title of being an ancestor of the messiah. In Elijah's case, as far as we know, he was childless (the Bible being silent on this), so there would be no confusion. However, Elijah is a type of Christ, as he raised people from the dead.

Hence, the conjecture here seems to be (with the explained exception of Elijah): that the phrase "God of X" is used in the Bible, it necessarily implies that "The God of X will be the Son of X."

For example, see the fourth item in the list given in https://www.newtestamentchristians.com/bible-study-resources/351-old-testament-prophecies-fulfilled-in-jesus-christ/ ("The God of Shem will be the Son of Shem")

I would like to know if anyone can think of a counterexample to Paul Chernoch's observation. More specifically---

QUESTION: Can anyone think of (with the noted exception of the prophet Elijah) an instance where the phrase "God of X" is used and it *does not* imply that "The God of X will be the Son of X"? (Perhaps in some bibles, the phrase "X's God" (or something like it) might be used in certain places.)

Thank you.

Comment: It's not obvious how "*The God of Shem will be the Son of Shem*" can be understood from Gen 9:26-27: "*He also said,
“Blessed be the LORD, the God of Shem;
and let Canaan be his servant.
May God enlarge Japheth,
and let him dwell in the tents of Shem,
and let Canaan be his servant.”*".

Comment: Didn't say it was; the question merely asks for counterexamples to the stated conjecture (if any exist).

Comment: My point was that the question says "*For example, see …*", yet I don't understand how the referenced item provides a suitable example.

Comment: At least in Jewish thought, the belief does not appear to be that God will become the son of the men in the messianic line, but rather that the Messiah would be a mere man or prophet. See Matt 22:45, where Jesus points out the the Pharisees that they may be mistaken in thinking this way "If then David calls him 'Lord,' how can he be his son?”

Answer (score 0):

First, that the premise that "The God of X will be the Son of X" is incorrect and/or has some exceptions beyond Elijah, can be established.  The statement that: *"Going through the ESV, I checked every verse with the construction 'God of X'. When X is the name of the person, these are the only names ever used"* is ***false.***

### Nahor

> The God of Abraham, and the **God of Nahor,** the God of their father,
> judge betwixt us. And Jacob sware by the fear of his father Isaac.
> (Genesis 31:3, KJV)

Nahor was Abraham's brother:

> And Terah lived seventy years, and begat Abram, Nahor, and Haran.
> (Genesis 11:26, KJV)

Nahor was also Abraham's grandfather:

> And Nahor lived after he begat Terah an hundred and nineteen years,
> and begat sons and daughters. (Genesis 11:25, KJV)

The phrasing "God of Abraham, and the God of Nahor, the God of their father," may well refer to the father of Abraham and Nahor, i.e. Terah--but Nahor himself would then be a separate line from that of Christ.  If this does not refer to Terah, who "their father" is remains quite vague, as this has already made a generational jump, and could quite well be expected to do so again.  The most logical application seems to be that "their father" refers to the mutual father of Abraham and Nahor, which was Terah (and Haran may not be mentioned on account of having died early, even before his father).

The fact that "God of Nahor" was not included in that original list may indicate that whomever compiled it was not comfortable with it fitting the desired paradigm, therefore omitted it.  However, the list is not then comprehensive, as was claimed.

### Jeshurun

Only three verses in the KJV translation name Jeshurun (shown below).

> But Jeshurun waxed fat, and kicked: thou art waxen fat, thou art grown
> thick, thou art covered with fatness; then he forsook God which made
> him, and lightly esteemed the Rock of his salvation. (Deuteronomy
> 32:14, KJV)
>
> And he was king in Jeshurun, when the heads of the people and the
> tribes of Israel were gathered together. (Deuteronomy 33:5, KJV)
>
> There is none like unto the **God of Jeshurun,** who rideth upon the
> heaven in thy help, and in his excellency on the sky. (Deuteronomy
> 33:26, KJV)

The second verse of these shows Jeshurun to have been the name of a place.  However, it is common for people's names to have become names of places, whether of cities (e.g. "city of David", "Dan", etc.) or countries (e.g. "land of Israel", "Moab", etc.), so this does not establish that it was only a place.  Looking closely at the first mention of Jeshurun, we find clear reference to him in the third-person masculine singular in Hebrew.  This is unlike cities, which are always grammatically feminine in Hebrew, for example "Dan" is a feminine-gendered noun in the following verse (which also shows it was the name of a city).

> And when Abram heard that his brother was taken captive, he armed his
> trained servants, born in his own house, three hundred and eighteen,
> and pursued them unto **Dan [N‑proper‑fs]**. (Genesis 14:14, KJV)

So having Jeshurun addressed as "he" and "him" indicates this was a man's name.  Arguing that "God of Jeshurun" only referenced the place of that name, and not the person of that name, would be a significant stretch, indicating subjective bias.

### Jesus

> That the God of our Lord Jesus Christ, the Father of glory, may give
> unto you the spirit of wisdom and revelation in the knowledge of him:
> (Ephesians 1:17, KJV)

The premise of the list-maker seems to be that if an uninspired/foreign person (non-prophet/non-Israelite) had used the expression, it was not to be counted.  But here we have the inspired apostle Paul, a Jew, speaking of the "God of our Lord Jesus Christ."

This verse has the opposite effect of that concluded in the OP.  In place of saying "The God of X will be the Son of X," it indicates that such a construction is invalid, because God is not the son of Jesus.

### Conclusion

The premise is invalid.  The original list compiler appears to have, whether mistakenly or deliberately, omitted several key occurrences of this "God of X" expression throughout the Bible--coincidentally the ones that would invalidate the premise.  It may even be that the compiler chose the ESV to avoid Deuteronomy 33:26, which the KJV has as "God of Jeshurun," but which reads "God, O Jeshurun" in the ESV.  However, the other two among these exceptions still exist in the ESV as well, rendering its "every verse" statement false, even with the ESV.

Comment: With regards to your conclusion---In the D-R, Deut 33:26: *There is no other God like the God of the rightest: he that is mounted upon the heaven is thy helper.*

Comment: In the ESV, Deuteronomy 33:26 says, "There is none like God, O Jeshurun", so the ESV did not use that construction for Jeshurun. As for Nahor, I missed that one. However, through Leah, descended from Nahor, Judah would be born. So that is not an exception either.